# Django bootstrap modal file upload form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Today Ive spent about 3 hours on the internet, looking for solution, but no luck. I want to have bootstrap modal (popup) and inside that modal i have form, to choose a number between 1-6 and upload picture file. So far i have these files:
Views.py:

```
SUJECTS = ["subject1", "subject3", "subject55",] 
@login_required
def create_exam(request, letnik_id, classes_id, subject_id):
    response_data = {}
    if subject_id in SUBJECTS:
        path = letnik_id + '/' + classes_id + '/' + subject_id
        form = ExamForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            exam = form.save(commit=False)
            exam.exam_user = request.user
            exam.exam_path = path
            exam.exam_file = request.FILES['exam_file']
            file_type = exam.exam_file.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                'error_message': 'File must be PNG, JPG ali JPEG',
                }
                return ??
            if Exam.objects.filter(exam_path=path, exam_number=exam.exam_number):
                context = {
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'Exam already exists!',
                }
                ??return??
            exam.save()
            return redirect('subject_id', letnik_id=letnik_id, classes_id=classes_id, subject_id=subject_id)
        context = {
        "form": form
        }
        return render(request, 'exam_form.html', context)
    raise Http404("Site does not exist")`
```

and i have exam_form.html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Dodaj Test
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
            {% if error_messages %}
                        <p style="color: #cc0000;" id="error_message">{{ error_message }}</p>
                    {% endif %}

                <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'create_exam' letnik_id=letnik_id classes_id=classes_id subject_id=subject_id %}" id="post-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                              for="inputEmail3">Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="" name="exam_number">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                          <option>5</option>
                          <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label"
                          for="inputPassword3" >Picture</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input  name="exam_file" type="file" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    </div>
                  </div>






            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            CLose
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that is included in tests.html(i just passed in the button,because the rest of test.html doesnt matter:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal" href="">
    Add Exam
</button>
{% include 'exam_form.html' %}
```

my views.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<letnik_id>[1-4])/(?P<classes_id>[A-G])/(?P<subject_id>[\w\-]+)/dodaj$', views.create_exam, name="create_exam"),
```

So i am trying to add bootstrap modal. When i click submit, the exam is created. But if i make an error for example if exam already exists or  file is not png/jpg/jpeg format, it gives me an error, since i dont know how to configure modal to display error and not close, if there are any errors.  Ive seen some use AJAX but i have no idea how to implement that. I would love it, if it would be possible to pass an error from views, without need to reload page, because hwhen page is reloaded, the modal closes.

Comment: I dont have your solution, but when I am in a similar situation after 3 hours...
the next day for sure you will solve it, slow down the pase and the solution will come as you are that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch `submit` in javascript

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : "/url/",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            //here data is the response. Based on this data, do your logic;
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you  for your answer! May i just ask you if that script is out of the box, or do i have to configure it with my views or something?I have to say, i know pretty much nothing about javascript

Comment: That script should be there in html. In same html or by importing js.

Comment: Could you please just tell me how to configure success: function (data)  {},
I would really appreciate it!

Comment: in `views`, do something pseudocode like`if form valid, return JsonResponse({"status": "success"}) else return JsonResponse({"status": "faliure"})`. So in javascript you can check it by `if data=="success" and vice versa

Comment: UPDATE: for the las hour ive been trying to configure my views.py with javascript, but no luck.I went through some tutorials, but none of them really worked for me..

Comment: Is request happens through javascript ?

Comment: I dont really know. I tried your code but i cant find a way to implement it, despite your tip

Answer (score 0):

I tried through both the ways (through ajax and through action ) but the issue is same, Just removing data-dismiss="modal" will work..,

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">CLose</button>
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            CLose
                </button>

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I just remove the data-dismiss="modal" from the the button of  bootstrap modal code, remove from both the button..than check it..

Comment: if we put data-dismiss="modal  it will close the modal, submit action will not perform, i am suggesting apart from above asked scenario, in case if anyone wanna perform submit action on the click of the button...